# Answer with no owner at all

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, display-names, deleted-accounts

[Windows Server Backup says the filename, directory name, or volume label is incorrect when adding another destination drive to the backup](https://serverfault.com/questions/80621/windows-server-backup-says-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-is-incor/90967#90967)

The answer has no owner at all, which is interesting. My first suspicion was that the user account had been deleted, but then doesn't that normally just change the answer to an anonymous user?

According to [SEDE the post has no owner AND no display name](https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/q/95417/).

Comment: Witness the power of this fully operational death star!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In destroying a user, the post field is replaced with the denormalized user display name.

So this is possible, though a user shouldn't technically ever have a blank display name.

Comment: Well, I figured this is a fairly edge case, this is the only one I've evern seen. Just as long as it's not something more sinister ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is what happens when you destroy a user.

Comment: Hmm, when I destroyed a user their answers were just changed to an un-associated account, but it still had a name against it. Oh well.